# Not able to install OpenCV on Python Alpine in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

Dockerfile -

any help would be appreciated!!

```
From python:3.6-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ADD text_extraction /app/

ADD text_extraction/text_extraction/requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: my guess is you should add `WORKDIR /app/text_extraction` as the 2nd last line, but if you don't provide the specific error message you're getting, and the directory structure of text_extraction, you run the risk of being downvoted and won't get useful feedback

Comment: What problem are you encountering?  What's in the `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: ERROR: Failed building wheel for cmake
  Failed to build numpy cmake
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for cmake which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python
this was the error iam getting